# Definition of prime element in a Euclidean ring does not make sense. Herstein - Topics in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm

**Herstein's Definition:** In the Euclidean ring $R$, a nonunit $\pi$ is said to be a *prime element* of $R$ if whenever $\pi=ab$, where $a,b \in R$, then one of $a$ or $b$ is a unit in R.

$\mathbb Q$ is a field and hence a Euclidean ring. In $\mathbb Q$ every element except $0$ is a unit. So there are no prime elements in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Correct.  There are no prime elements in ${\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: Everything you've said is correct... and you didn't lay your finger on any contradiction that the definition caused. You are quite clearly encountering [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) caused by a conflict between what you have written (very clearly and correctly) and some conception you had in your mind. A successful struggle with cognitive dissonance usually results in a boost in learning!

Comment: fyi: what Herstein defines is an *irreducible* element  (atom), if $\neq 0.\,$ But in Euclidean domains we have that: irreducible $\,\Rightarrow\,$ prime (i.e. $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,b).$ Conversely, prime $\,\Rightarrow\,$ irreducible is always true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually yes, There is no prime elements in $\mathbb Q$.

Every element in $\mathbb Q$ is divisible by another element in $\mathbb Q$

Think about any element in $\mathbb Q$.

For example, $3 \in \mathbb Q$ is not prime because we have that $\frac{1}{3} \times {9} = 3$

In general, an element $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ is in the form of $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b$ are both integers and $b \neq 0$.

Now $\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb Q$ and $a \in \mathbb Q$ and $\frac{1}{b} \times a = \frac{a}{b}$ and so you can't have a prime element in $\mathbb Q$

However, That definition is actually the definition for an irreducible element. However, sometimes irreducibility implies prime and in a euclidean domain, it's true because a euclidean domain is also a unique factorization domain.

However, In a general integral domain, Irreducible doesn't imply prime.

The definition for a prime element is the following.

$p$ is said to be a prime element , if $p$ is a positive non unit element 
and if $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$

Now to give you an example where there is an irreducible element which is not prime.

Consider the integral domain $\sqrt{-5}$

Now $2$ is an irreducible element that divides the product $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}) = 6$.

However $2$ does not divide any of the factors and hence it's not prime.

Comment: The def. I gave is the same that Herstein gives

Comment: yes that's why I said that irreducible element imply prime in a euclidean domain.

And so the definition of an irreducible element and prime is equivalent in that case.

However, In an integral domain, You have to distinguish between the two definitions.

Comment: So, prime elements and irreducible elements are the same in a UFD, but not in an integral domain? Can you give an example please?

Comment: I added an example in my answer.
Ask me if you have any more questions :)

Comment: By the domain $\sqrt{-5}$, do you mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's right: $\mathbb{Q}$ has no prime elements besides $0$ (and $0$ may or may not be a prime, depending on your conventions).  This shouldn't be too surprising, though.  Prime elements generate prime ideals.  But since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, its only ideals are $(0)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

By the way, your definition of a prime element is not standard.  The definition you've stated is usually that of an [irreducible element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element).  The linked article specifically discusses the difference between the two.

Comment: Herstein is specifically talking about euclidean rings, where primeness and irreducibility are equivalent, so this definition is technically correct.  But I agree that because students will eventually want to generalize to other rings, it would have been better to use the word "irreducible" here.

Comment: I believe (but am not sure) that $0$ is, by convention, not a prime element even though it generates a prime ideal.  Herstein's definition seems designed to adhere to this convention.

Comment: I dislike this convention because of the nice result that in a commutative ring $R$, an ideal $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is a domain.  Specifically, it allows one to characterize domains as commutative rings in which $(0)$ is prime.  For reference, Dummit and Foote allow $0$ to be prime.

Comment: Are the regular prime numbers in $\mathbb Z$ also prime elements? Aren't the prime numbers in $\mathbb Z$ also prime numbers in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Are prime numbers different from prime elements?

Comment: @SpamIAm:  This convention does not preclude your characterization of domains, or of prime ideals.

Comment: @AlJebr No, primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ are units in $\mathbb{Q}$ (just take $1/p$), so they are not prime.

Comment: @WillO I don't understand your comment.  I claim that $R$ is an integral domain iff $0$ is prime, where I call an element prime iff it generates a prime ideal.  But your definition does not permit $0$ to be prime.

Comment: @spamiam:  In your first comment, you wanted to characterize $R$ as an integral domain iff $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is a prime ideal.  In your new comment, you want to characterize $R$ as an integral domain iff the element $0$ is called prime.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: @WillO Well, if $(a)$ can be a prime ideal without $a$ being a prime element, I will be even more unhappy with the definitions. :)

Comment: @spamiam:  To be totally pedantic:  You (at least at first) wanted to characterize $R$ as a domain iff the ideal generated by $0$ is prime.  This criterion makes no mention of the element $0$.  Because the convention I described concerns only the element $0$, it cannot be relevant to your criterion.

Comment: I agree with @WillO here. The usual definition of a prime element is a *nonzero* nonunit $p$ such that $p \mid ab$ implies $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. Then $x$ is a prime element iff $(x)$ is a *nonzero* prime ideal.

Comment: @WillO Some authors do allow $0$ to be prime.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's right. There are no primes in $\mathbb{Q}$.

On a different note, many people would say that what you call a *prime* is an **irreducible.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are no primes in a field. $5$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$

More generally if you have two rings $A\subset B$, being a prime in $A$ does not imply being a prime in $B$. As an example take $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. Then we have $3$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ while $3=(1+\sqrt{-2})(1-\sqrt{-2})$ is not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Comment: This. Most people probably think of the statement "5 is prime" has being a universal fact, not something that's only true in certain contexts. I vaguely remember something about limits that exist in one field but don't exist in a slightly larger field.